# Добавление записи в БД

Tags: php, база-данных, insert

Заполняю все нужные поля. Нажимаю ADD RECORD (после чего значения должны занестись в таблицу в бд), но
при нажатии на кнопку ADD RECORD ничего не происходит.

Пришел к выводу, что запрос просто не выполняется. В чем может быть ошибка?

```
if(isset($_POST['author']) &&
   isset($_POST['title']) &&
   isset($_POST['category']) &&
   isset($_POST['year']) &&
   isset($_POST['isbn']))
{
    $stmt->bindParam(':author', $author);
    $stmt->bindParam(':title', $title);
    $stmt->bindParam(':category', $category);
    $stmt->bindParam(':year', $year);
    $stmt->bindParam(':isbn', $isbn);

    /*$author = $_POST['author'];
    $title = $_POST['title'];
    $category =$_POST['category'];
    $year = $_POST['year'];
    $isbn = $_POST['isbn'];*/ // Не знаю нужна ли эта часть кода

    $stmt = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO classics (author,title,category,year,isbn) VALUES(:author,:title,:category,:year,:isbn)");  

    $stmt->execute();
}
```

Comment: у вас в коде всё в той же последовательности?

Comment: `bindParam` должен быть после `prepare`. но еще раньше переменные конечно должны быть определены. если вы задаётесь вопросом "нужна ли эта часть кода", то у меня для вас плохие новости )))

Comment: Вы объявили параметры запроса, но не указали их значения. Посмотрите внимательно все примеры и комментарии по PDO::prepare() http://php.net/pdo_prepare

Comment: @artoodetoo: нет такой причины закрытия.

Comment: @NickVolynkin, я это понимаю. но формулировка "необходимо уточнить вопрос" не отражает суть проблемы. А проблема есть. Нормальная ситуация когда автор знает что хочет сделать, но не умеет. А когда автор просто копирует фрагменты в одном месте и просит довести до ума в другом месте — это имитация.

Answer (score 1):

Если кратко - ошибка в последовательности выполняемых команд.

Давайте разберемся с последовательностью:

1. Проверить наличие данных, за это отвечает условный оператор `if` и набор проверок вида `isset($_POST['author'])`. Функция `isset()` проверяет есть ли у переменной значение.
2. Получить данные из запроса в локальные переменные. Этот как раз блок кода, который у Вас закомментирован вида `$author = $_POST['author'];`
3. Подготовить запрос. Это строка `$stmt = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO classics (author,title,category,year,isbn) VALUES(:author,:title,:category,:year,:isbn)");`, объект запроса теперь хранится в переменной `$stmt`
4. Заполнить переменные в запросе вот таким образом: `$stmt->bindParam(':author', $author);`. Данная строка переменной `:author` в запросе выше присвоит значение из переменной `$author`, полученное в пункте 2.
5. Выполнить запрос: `$stmt->execute();`

Таким образом, Ваш код должен выглядеть так:

```
if(isset($_POST['author']) &&
   isset($_POST['title']) &&
   isset($_POST['category']) &&
   isset($_POST['year']) &&
   isset($_POST['isbn']))
{
    $author = $_POST['author'];
    $title = $_POST['title'];
    $category =$_POST['category'];
    $year = $_POST['year'];
    $isbn = $_POST['isbn'];

    $stmt = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO classics (author,title,category,year,isbn) VALUES(:author,:title,:category,:year,:isbn)");  

    $stmt->bindParam(':author', $author);
    $stmt->bindParam(':title', $title);
    $stmt->bindParam(':category', $category);
    $stmt->bindParam(':year', $year);
    $stmt->bindParam(':isbn', $isbn);

    $stmt->execute();
}
```

На будущее также рекомендую прочитать про [`filter_*`](http://php.net/manual/ru/book.filter.php) функции.